# SyntaxHighlighter (javascript) problem with <del>

Tags: javascript, syntaxhighlighter

I am using syntaxhighlighter (http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) with a php source code with the ins and del tag.

What I would like to do is to have syntaxhighligher ignore those html tags so that they can be parsed correctly. So I'd like to to display:

> <del>`test`</del>

instead of the default

```
<del>test</del>
```

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
extended_valid_elements : 'del',
        custom_elements : 'del'
```

in `tinyMCE.init({`  .... JS method

http://netofdotnet.com